# Magento 1.9.2.3 deadlocks from core_cache table

Tags: cache, magento1.9.2.3

We have deployed the site in ELB with 2 instance and cache & session are stored in Database, but we often getting deadlock issue in `core_cache` table

```
a:4:{i:0;s:469:"SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO core_cache (
                    `id`,
                    `data`,
                    `create_time`,
                    `update_time`,
                    `expire_time`)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `data`=VALUES(`data`),
                    `expire_time`=VALUES(`expire_time`)";i:1;s:827:"#0 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_exe$

#1 /var/app/current/citygoo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO cor...', Array)
#4 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO cor...', Array)
#5 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Varien/Cache/Backend/Database.php(211): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO cor...', Array)
#6 /var/app/current/citygoo/lib/Zend/Cache/Core.php(390): Varien_Cache_Backend_Database->save('";s:3:"url";s:34:"/api/rest/v3/pentalog/reservations";s:11:"script_name"$
```

We are facing this issue in Production, please help us.

**Hosted in AWS**

Comment: When you say "deployed the site in ELB", do you mean you are hosting in AWS?

Comment: Any solution for this?